QGIS georeferencer vector snapping
In QGIS, when georeferencing vector files, is it possible to enable snapping that works within the georeferencer window ?  Snapping works when choosing coordinates from the map canvas, but doesn't seem to work with vectors in the georeferencer window.

It's a missing functionality. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/52306.

Thank-you for your reply !
